# I need to fix this two problems in the program. Based on the inputs, I need a fix on the code to produce the desired output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void handle(FILE *np)// this is to handle newline characters
{
    putc('\n', np);

}
/* skip a C multi-line comment, return the last byte read or EOF */
int m_cmnt(FILE *fp, int *lineno_p) {
FILE *np = stdout;
int prev, ch, replacement = ' ';
for (prev = 0; (ch = getc(fp)) != EOF; prev = ch) {
    if (prev == '\\' && ch == 'n') {
        replacement = '\n';
        ++*lineno_p;
        }
    if (prev == '*' && ch == '/')
        return replacement;
    }

return EOF;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
FILE *fp = stdin, *np = stdout;
int ch,prev;
bool String = 0;
const char *filename = "<stdin>";
int lineno = 1;

fp = fopen(filename, "r");
np = fopen(argv[2], "w");

if (argc > 1) {
    if ((fp = fopen(filename = argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file %s: \n",
                filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
if (argc > 2) {
    if ((np = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open output file %s: \n",
                argv[2]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == '\n')
        lineno++;
    /* file pointer currently not inside a string */
    if (!String) {
        if (ch == '/') {
            ch = getc(fp);
            if (ch == '\n')
                lineno++;
            if (ch == '*') {
                int startline = lineno;
                ch = m_cmnt(fp, &lineno);
                if (ch == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: error: unterminated comment started on line %d\n",
                            filename, lineno, startline);
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    break;
                }
                putc(ch, np);
            } else {
                putc('/', np);
                putc(ch, np);
            }
        }
         else if ( ch=='\\')/*to handle newline character*/
            {
                prev=ch ;
                ch= getc(fp) ;
                switch(ch)
                {
                    case 'n'  :
                                handle(np);
                                 break ;
                    /*default   :
                                 putc(prev , np) ;
                                 putc(ch , np) ;
                                 break ;*/
                }
            }
        else {
            putc(ch, np);
        }
    } else {
        putc(ch, np);
    }
    if (ch == '"' || ch == '\'')
        String = !String;
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(np);
//remove(arr[1]);
//rename("temp.txt", arr[1]);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have been working on this project for almost more than a week now. I have asked many questions on this site to help me get the desired result.The basics of this program is to remove multiline comments from source file and write the rest to some output file. **It also need to to ignore any thing that is inside a string literal or character literal(like escaped characters).**   Now I have come to finalize it but I still need to achieve this two outputs shown below

```
INPUT1 = //*SOMECOMMENT*/  
OUTPUT1 = /
INPUT2 = "this \"test"/*test*/
OUTOUT2 = "this \"test"
```

The current(erroneous) output is shown below

```
INPUT1 = //*SOMECOMMENT*/  
OUTPUT1 = //*SOMECOMMENT*/    This is wrong.
INPUT2 = "this \"test"/*test*/
OUTOUT2 = "this \"test"/*test*/   This is also wrong.
```

The program don't work for the case where a comment comes after a forward slash(/) and the second failure of the program is it don't ignore escape character inside a string or character literal. I need a fix on this two problems please.

Comment: What is the syntax of the source language? Is it C code? You are likely going to have to implement a real parser for this language, so you will probably need a description of the syntax in BNF. If it's an existing language, you might want to consider using an existing parser for it; e.g. if it's C, can you use Clang to build an AST and then perform your manipulations on the AST rather than on text?

Comment: @ Daniel Pryden. The language is C but I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: BNF = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Comment: please guys I just need fix on the code.

Comment: It may be time to read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  It's fiddly looking at your code.  It isn't neatly laid out.  I've got a program SCC (Strip C Comments), but it also handles C++17 with quotes in numbers, binary constants, and raw strings, all of which cause immense complications that you don't need to be concerned about.  That alone makes it a less than stellar exemplar for you.  However, if you want to look at it, then poke around in https://github.com/jleffler/scc-snapshots for the code etc.  There are releases there.

Comment: for ease of understanding of the posted code: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement; `fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file %s: \n",
                filename);`  when the error indication comes from a C library function, should also output (to stderr) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()`  does all the above correctly

Comment: regarding: `const char *filename = "<stdin>";
fp = fopen(filename, "r");`  the string: `<stdin>` is not a valid string to pass to `fopen()`

Comment: regarding: `<stdin>`  perhaps you were trying to access the input file stream descriptor 0?  perhaps you wanted to use a file* instead.  In that case the function: `fdopen( stdin )`  would do the job

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.

Comment: what is the difference between this code and simply echoing the input?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you want to read an input stream of characters, divide that stream into tokens, and then emit only a subset of those tokens, I think [Lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) is exactly the tool you're looking for.

If I understand your comment correctly, the file you're trying to read in and transform is itself C code. So you will need to build up a Lex definition of the C language rules.

A quick search turned up [this Lex specification of the ANSI C grammar](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html). I cannot vouch for its accuracy or speak to its licensing. At first glance it seems to only support C89. But it is probably enough to point you in the right direction.